Which algorithm can I use to number the graph as follows

Each node in the above graph has been numbered.
I am trying to find the graph traversal algorithm that can be used to number the graph in this order. Appreciate if anyone can suggest an algorithm that can number them in the above order

Is the BBXX the node number you are refering to? It looks like a topological sort, probably you need to make it a bit custom if you want the edges labelled as "else" to show up before the "then".

What are you really trying to do? Visit all the nodes in what looks like a three-address code tree? Or to "interpret" the code and only follow the arrows from the specific node (meaning e.g. BB15 and BB16 are mutually exclusive)?

@CarlosRoldán. No that is the node number I am referring to numbers from 0 -48. For instance 0: a:= 1 in the first instruction 0 is the number

@Someprogrammerdude Yeah this is a CFG and I want to number each TAC in the above order.

It's still not clear to me if you want to visit all the instructions ("nodes") or just the ones being interpreted. Like for example, do you want to visit all of the instructions labeled 36 to 48; Or e.g. 36, 37, 41, 42, 44, 47, 48 and skip 38 to 40, 43, 45 and 46. In short, do you need to list all instructions, or do you need to interpret them in the correct order.

The order you give is consistent with a topological sort using Kahn's algorithm.
To get exactly the order you specify, when the algorithm chooses between multiple nodes that are available simultaneously, you have to choose the one with the highest BB label.
